# ls ignoring extensions when colorizing with LS_COLORS

Tags: terminal, shell, colors, zsh, ls

I'm trying to set `LS_COLORS` to colorize my ls output, but for some reason it is ignoring any file match patterns.  It is correctly coloring executables, directories, etc., but it seems to be completely ignoring any of my file match patterns starting with *.

I know the string itself is correct because I have tried it on another machine and it works as expected.  I also know that these are not being overwritten by the catch-all values like `fi` and `di` because when I remove those parts of the `LS_COLORS` string  I simply don't get any colored output.  I've confirmed that I'm using GNU ls and not some other flavor of ls.

The string itself is pretty long but here's a truncated version I've created for testing (it's the same as my real `LS_COLORS`, I've just removed about 200 extensions from the beginning of the string):

```sh
*.war=38;5;215:*.wav=38;5;136;1:*.webloc=38;5;116:*.webm=38;5;115:*.webp=38;5;97:*.wma=38;5;137;1:*.wmv=38;5;114:*.woff=38;5;66:*.woff2=38;5;66:*.wrl=38;5;216:*.wv=38;5;136;1:*.wvc=38;5;136;1:*.xcconfig=1:*.xcf=38;5;7:*.xcsettings=1:*.xcuserstate=1:*.xcworkspacedata=1:*.xib=38;5;208:*.xla=38;5;76:*.xln=38;5;7:*.xls=38;5;112:*.xlsx=38;5;112:*.xlsxm=38;5;112;4:*.xltm=38;5;73;4:*.xltx=38;5;73:*.xml=38;5;178:*.xpi=38;5;215:*.xpm=38;5;97:*.xsd=38;5;178:*.xsh=38;5;41:*.yaml=38;5;178:*.yml=38;5;178:*.z[0-9]{0,2}=38;5;239:*.zcompdump=38;5;241:*.zig=38;5;81:*.zlogin=1:*.zlogout=1:*.zprofile=1:*.zsh=38;5;172:*.zshenv=1:*.zwc=38;5;241:*.zx[0-9]{0,2}=38;5;239:bd=38;5;68:ca=38;5;17:cd=38;5;113;1:di=38;5;30:do=38;5;127:ex=38;5;208;1:pi=38;5;126:fi=0:ln=target:mh=38;5;222;1:no=0:or=48;5;196;38;5;232;1:ow=38;5;220;1:sg=48;5;3;38;5;0:su=38;5;220;1;3;100;1:so=38;5;197:st=38;5;86;48;5;234:tw=48;5;235;38;5;139;3:
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Don't you need to set `LS_COLORS` (plural)?

Comment: I think it also depends on which system you are. IIRC on BSD the syntax is different compared to linux.

Comment: @egmont sorry, that was a typo. I am in fact using `$LS_COLORS`.  Fixed in the post above.

Comment: @mpy correct - on Macs it uses `$LSCOLORS` (no underscore) and the format is totally different.  However, I'm not on a BSD system and I *am* getting colorized output.  It's just coloring any file the same color and ignoring the color codes I've added for extensions.

Comment: The given value works for me on Ubuntu 23.04, ls (GNU coreutils) version 9.1. What's your distro and ls version on the computer where it works and on the one where it doesn't? Also, are you running screen/tmux by any chance?

Comment: @egmont this is on my Synology NAS, so it is using Synology's own DSM distro.  It's Debian-based, though, so it recognizes LS_COLORS but not LSCOLORS.  LS version is 'ls (GNU coreutils) 9.3' on both machines.  I have tried both with and without running tmux with identical results.

Comment: It works for me with self-compiled vanilla coreutils 9.3, too. Would be interesting to see if one binary copied to the other computer, or vice versa, work, to locate whether the issue is in the binary (maybe Synology breaks it by some patch, maybe an ls bug is triggered by some compile options etc.) or in the surrounding environment (e.g. some environment variable, config file, terminfo etc.).

Comment: It's possible, but I don't think I can just lift up the binary and move it. The working system is a Mac that I've installed GNU ls on.  I've verified that I'm using the right ls on that machine by typing out the whole path to it, and I've verified that it is version 9.3.  But of course it's a different OS so the compiled binaries will be different.  Since you self-compiled, are there any compilation flags that might affect this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was edited to include an answer. Please post an answer, then mark it as solution if you're sure it will help people. Don't include "SOLVED" or anything alike in the title either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(tl;dr for anyone else encountering this: double-check that the files you are looking at are not executable by you. If they are, then they will all be given the color of your 'ex' section in $LS_COLORS instead of the color corresponding to their extension.)

Turns out this was operator error. All the files in my test directory were unexpectedly set as executable, and thus they were all given the color I had assigned to executable files (orange). When I manually removed the executable bit from files with an extension that should be colored based on the contents of $LS_COLORS, it worked as expected.